# Populating one to many relationship in sails js without using primary key

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

Every example code of one to many in sails/waterline documentation assumes the primary key is the association between two models (I think).

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many

However i have models that have a referral column that references some other values similar to

```
User
{ 
    id (primary): <int>
    email: <string>
} 

recordings
{
    id (primary): <int>
    email: <that email from user>
}
```

atm im trying

```
userModel.js
{
   attributes: {
      email: {
         type: 'string',
            size: 255,
            unique: true
         },
      },
      queries: { 
        columnName: 'email',
        model: 'recordings'
      }
      .....
   }
}

recordingsModel.js
{
   attributes: {
      email: {
         type: 'string',
            size: 255,
         },
      },
      queries: { 
        model: 'user'
      }
      .....
   }
}
```

and in the Controller

```
sails.models.user
     .find()
     .populate('queries')
     .exec(function (err, results) {

 });
```

But i get the error
: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '__queries.queries' in 'field list'

Does anyone have a good tutorial for one to many relationships in waterline because the documentation on there site is pretty bad so i feel im just not understanding how to design the models.

Comment: In recordingsModel you have attribute ```queries``` and thic column does not exist. Try removing it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, what you want is to be able to set up your `userModel` and `recordingsModel` models such that, by giving a recording a certain value for `email`, it will automatically be associated with any users that share that email.  This is not something that the Waterline (the Sails ORM) supports.

Instead, your best option is to set the models up as indicated in the documentation:

```
// userModel.js
{
   attributes: {
      email: {
         type: 'string',
            size: 255,
            unique: true
         },
      },
      recordings: { 
        collection: 'recordingsModel',
        via: 'user'
      }
      .....
   }
}

// recordingsModel.js
{
   attributes: {
      email: {
         type: 'string',
            size: 255,
         },
      },
      user: { 
        model: 'userModel'
      }
   }
}
```

My guess is that you're trying to avoid having to look up a user ID in order to associate a new recording with it.  You can do this if you make `email` the primary key of the `userModel`; then when you create a new recording, you can set its `user` to an email address and voila: the two are linked.

Comment: Unfortunately, im tacking sails on top of a pre-existing database Im not gonna change since other systems rely on it. Unfortunately sails seems to be a bit more opinionated then i had hoped. Might drop waterline for a tradition mysql connection because of this.

Comment: You can always use [`.query`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query) to make a custom SQL query from Waterline as well.

Comment: Ya but then whats the point of using waterline? I am doing that more and more for each endpoint unfortunately.